# Variable passed to Cron job with bind results in undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I'm parsing some HTML to get at a list of data, for each item in the list I'm scheduling a number of Cron jobs. Each set of jobs is added to an array to keep track of them. 
The snippet of code below, shows a for loop iterating through the list of data from the webpage, and a Cron job being created for each iteration. Variable i is passed into the anonymous function when each job is created, but attempts to print this.i results in undefined.

Is there something that I am missing here, or can someone suggest a way to resolve this?

```js
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

for(var i = 0; i < dataList.length; i++) {
  new CronJob('*/20 * * * * * ', function() {
    console.log(this.i)
  }.bind( { i: this.i } ), null, true, 'Europe/Dublin');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue with:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  new CronJob('* * * * * * ', function(x) {
    console.log(x)
  }.bind(null, i), null, true, 'Europe/Dublin');
}
```